# Caliburn.Micro treats hexadecimal values as wrong input

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I use Caliburn.Micro in my C# WPF MVVM application. I have TextBox in my application:

```
<TextBox Name="Param1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

and Param1 property in ViewModel:

```
public Byte Param1
{
    get { return this._param1; }
    set
    {
        this._param1 = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Param1);
    }
}
```

But when I try to input 8-bit hexadecimal value in this textbox (for example 1F, C0, 2A) then the borders of TextBox are colored in red. Probably Caliburn.Micro treats hexadecimal values as wrong input because decimal 8-bit values (for example: 101, 97, 64) are treated as correct input. How to make Caliburn.Micro treat hexadecimal values as correct input? How can I do it in my case? Your help will be appreciated highly.

Comment: For one thing, has nothing to do with `Caliburn` because a `TextBox` in a regular WPF app does the same thing.

Comment: a byte is a decimal from 0-255, so it's natural that  it can't convert "1F" into a number, because it's not a valid number. You need a `ValueConverter` which does the conversion from text (input) to decimal (byte, output)

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn Micro does not provide by default an hexadecimal converter. You have to write your own converter. Something like:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(byte), typeof(string))]
public class HexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte byteValue = (byte)value;
        return byteValue.ToString("X", culture);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte byteValue;
        string stringValue = (string)value;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (Byte.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, culture, out byteValue))
        {
            return byteValue;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Now you have two options:

1. define a specific binding for the `Param1` TextBox; in that binding you can use the `HexConverter`;
2. on the other side, if you need to use that converter all over your application, you can configure in the right way the `ConventionManager` class.

The first solution is quite simple, so I will show just the second one.
We have to say to Caliburn that we want to use the `HexConverter` each time that we have a named `TextBox` control "linked" to a `byte` property.

So we can do it in the `Bootstrapper`:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private static IValueConverter hexConverter = new HexConverter();

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Show your starting view model */
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter = (binding, dependencyProperty, propertyInfo) =>
            {
                if (dependencyProperty == UIElement.VisibilityProperty && typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                {
                    binding.Converter = ConventionManager.BooleanToVisibilityConverter;
                    return;
                }

                if (dependencyProperty == TextBox.TextProperty && typeof(byte).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                {
                    binding.Converter = hexConverter;
                    return;
                }
            };
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the `ApplyValueConverter` action, with an *anonymous* method which uses a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` if the binded dependency property is the `VisibilityProperty` and the source property is a `bool` (this is Caliburn default).

Moreover if Caliburn is binding the `Text` dependency property to a `byte`, then it will use our HexConverter.

I hope it will help you.